# Select object from combobox title filled with hashtable of object in C#

Tags: c#, combobox, hashtable

I have a C# form application. I have a hashtable of object (id - title ...) .
I fill the combobox with the id and the title. When someone select an item, i get the id and title, extract the id and get the object from the hashtable.

I use List where I need some sorting.

Is there a better way to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create derived class from 'KeyedCollection' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438.aspx. 
Let's assume it will contain items of 'SomeItem' class. That class have properties Id, Name and some others. Set this KeyedCollection as ComboBox datasource. Then set ValueMemeber = "Id", DisplayMember = "Name"; After that you can cast "SelectedItem" to 'SomeItem' class and work with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SortedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx)